# PowerShell Script to verify the .NET version for a list of remote Servers

Tags: windows, powershell

We are attempting to update Windows 10 builds 19041-19044 to the latest windows 10 build 19045. The script to update to 19045 is failing & we suspect its due to the .NET version.

That being said, I need a PowerShell script that can take a list of windows servers & runs a command to check the .NET version.

I'm more of a python guy & new to Powershell but I would thinking I would just need to make a list of the servers, figure out the command to check for the .NET version & then write a for loop going through the list executing the command for each entry to check the .NET version.

Do you guys have any ideas or where I should start? I'm completely new to PowerShell & would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Command that checks:

```
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse |
Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | 
Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | 
Select PSChildName, version
```

I have tried using the `Invoke-Command` but haven't had any luck just yet. This what I got so far but haven't been able to test just yet.

```
Invoke-Command -Computer (Get-Content results.txt) `
               -ScriptBlock {
                    Get-Website |
                        ForEach-Object {
                         $site = $_
                         $_.bindings.collection |
                            ForEach-Object {                           
                                [pscustomobject]@{
                                    serverName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                                    name=$site.Name
                                    Protocol=$_.Protocol
                                    Bindings=$_.BindingInformation
                                    path=$site.PhysicalPath
                                }
                            }
                        }
               } | Export-Csv -Path C:\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I'm going to get a lot of flak from mklement0 over this comment.  But there is no reason to try to solve this issue with one instruction.  The best way of solving this issue is to write in multiple line of code and debug one line at a time.  Remove the Where and get all properties.  Then filter until you get desired results.  You can get all properties with : Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Select-Object -Property *

Comment: Yeah that is a fair point, I'll try removing the where/get all & then just filter it down. Thanks for the response.